# Query two models in Class Based View

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-queryset

I am attempting to run more than two queries within my `IndexView`, and display the results within my template. However, I can't seem to add both `Entry.objects.filter(date=today_date)` and `Savings.objects.filter(id=1)` to `get_context_data` without it erroring out saying:

> Reverse for 'entry-update' with arguments '('',)' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['tracker/entry/update/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

How would I go about pulling data from two different models into one view? More specifically, how would I get something like this to work:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    et = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    et['filter'] = Entry.objects.filter(date=today_date), (Savings.objects.filter(id=1))
    return et
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

**views.py**

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'argent/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'object_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Entry.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        et = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        et['filter'] = Entry.objects.filter(date=today_date)

        return et
```

**models.py**

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,)
    euros = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=900, blank=True, null=True)
    euros_sum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    xrate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    dollars_sum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    daily_savings_dollars = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    daily_savings = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('argent:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def item_date(self):
        row_title = self.date
        return row_title


class Savings(models.Model):
    total_spent_euros = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    total_spent_dollars = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    total_savings = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('argent:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

EDIT: I added more detail to this post.

Comment: What error do you get ? Because this is the good approach. You add in your context the new queryset result. And in object_list you have the result of get_queryset() method.

Comment: The errors mostly state that `get_queryset` or `get_context_data` are already defined, and as a result cannot be used again, which makes sense. But what I can't figure out how to do is join multiple queries within a single `get_queryset` or `get_context_data` function. What I am trying to do is pull data from  `Entry.objects.filter(date=today_date)` and also from `Savings.objects.filter(id=1)`, and then display both results within the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your problem of getting two queryset result in one page :

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    et = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    et['entry_qs'] = Entry.objects.filter(date=today_date)
    et['savings_qs'] = Savings.objects.filter(id=1)
    return et
```

Now in your template, you have acces to this two querysets.
`{{ entry_qs }}` and `{{ savings_qs }}`

About your error

> Reverse for 'entry-update' with arguments '('',)' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['tracker/entry/update/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

I suppose you write a bad template `url` in your template. You use url `entry-update` without an argument. So Django can't reverse this url. Because this doesn't exist. You need to pass an argument to this url

```
{% url 'entry-update' pk %}  # replace pk by primary key of the correct object
```

Comment: That works! It makes total sense now that I see it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you